# IOS/Swift --- Como puedo detectar cuando se da un click en un UITextField o cuando tiene Focus

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo varios textfields y necesito saber cuando se presiona alguno o cuando alguno tiene focus para así cambiarle el color del borde?

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.placeholder,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "ITCAvantGardeStd-Bk", size: 16)! // Note the !
    ]

    txtUsername.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Correo electrónico", attributes:attributes)
    txtPassword.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Contraseña", attributes:attributes)

}
```

Gracias

Comment: Si es posible hacer lo que solicitas, puedas agregar una parte del código que tienes? Así mejora tu pregunta y no recibe votos negativos.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar los métodos propios del `TextField` debes agregar a tu clase el `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class TuViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Y delegar en el `ViewDidLoad` a todos los `TextField` para activar las funciones.

```
txtUsername.delegate = self
```

Una vez realizado eso puedes acceder a las funciones relacionadas con los `TextField`.

Uniendo todo en tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
class TuViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //1. Agregas el delegate a los TextField
    txtUsername.delegate = self
    txtPassword.delegate = self

    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.placeholder,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "ITCAvantGardeStd-Bk", size: 16)! // Note the !
    ]

    txtUsername.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Correo electrónico", attributes:attributes)
    txtPassword.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Contraseña", attributes:attributes)

}
//2. Puedes acceder a los métodos de los TextField
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { //Cuando haces click o empiezas a editar.
    //3. Aquí verificas qué TextField tiene el foco
    if txtUsername.isFirstResponder {
        //4. Cambias el borde
    }

    if txtPassword.isFirstResponder {
        //5. Cambias el borde
    }
}

}
```